# PHP - How to fetch posts if the location of the post matches the location of the currently logged in user

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently developing a newsfeed app with php. User's are assigned a location. User's can create posts which are assigned the location of the user. So far the newsfeed is being populated by all posts regardless of location. What I need is to populate the newsfeed by posts where the post location matches the user location.

I want the currently logged in user's location to match the posts with the same location and then populate to the newsfeed. This code doesnt work. 
 Any help would be great!

```
 public function getDashboard($posts_location)
  {
 $posts = Post::where('location', $posts_location);

 if(Auth::user()->location = $posts_location) {
 return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo in the post, but there is an assignment instead of an equality check
`Auth::user()->location = $posts_location`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgetten the ->get().  And as Giacomo Cosimato stated in the comments above, there is an equality check error in your if statement.

```
public function getDashboard($posts_location)
{
     $posts = Post::where('location', $posts_location)->get();

     if(empty($posts->first()->id))
         return abort('404');

     if(Auth::user()->location == $posts_location) {
          return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
     }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#http-exceptions

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the help. I've used your code but I get this error         :Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PostController::getDashboard().  Any ideas?

Comment: $post_locations should be coming in via your routes.  You might have something like this Route::get('/locations/{slug}', 'Controller@getDashboard'); where "slug" will be the variable sent in as $posts_location.  So if the visitor goes to www.yourwebsite.com/locations/alberta, $posts_location would the be equal to "alberta".

Comment: Thanks Troy. So I must add $post_locations to my route..Is there any where else I should add it?

Comment: That should be all you need.  Once you get the variable in your controller you just need to perform your logic and return the view.  You will also want to consider how to handle 404 errors on these pages since a user could now trigger this method by typing in www.yourwebsite.com/locations/somewhere-that-doesnt-exist

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. 'middleware' => 'auth' in the route should eliminate this risk right?

Comment: Middleware are different than throwing a 404.  I've edited my answer to demonstrate.  Basically, middleware will prevent anyone who isn't authorised from reaching your getDashboard() method.  The 404 error should be thrown when you don't actually have content to show based on the variable sent into $posts_location.  So for this, you need to wait until you are in the getDashboard() method.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, this is all I needed

```
  public function getDashboard()
  {
     $posts = Post::where('location', '=', Auth::user()->location)
     ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
  }
```

Thanks for the help guys!!